# I think I am over complicating this for myself

Tags: loops

So I'm practicing simple python as revision for school and have come across the challenge "Write an algorithm that asks the user to input a number. The program should then count from 0 and for every other number it should output "Boo".

```
for count in range(count,10):
    print(count)
    count +=2
    if count % 2 == 0:
         print("boo")
```

That is what I tried to use, I messed around with it a bit to try make it work but for some reason I just can't think of the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```py
for num in range(0, count + 1):
    if num % 2 == 0:
         print(num)
    else: 
        print("boo")
```

Let's look at every line:

`for num in range(0, count + 1):`

The number on the left of `range` is the starting point. The number on the right is the number it counts up to.

I changed `count` to `num` to remove some confusion in the syntax. The `range` function creates a list of numbers from 0 to (n - 1), so I add 1 to count so it will count to n instead of n - 1.

```py
    if num % 2 == 0:
         print(num)
    else: 
        print("boo")
```

`num % 2` checks if a number is even. 0 will technically be considered "even" because 0 % 2 = 0. Because the algorithm starts with 0, we will have this print the num, and every other num (the odd numbers) will print "boo"